# How to run two Oracle stored procedure one by one from Unix batch file

Tags: oracle, shell, unix, stored-procedures, sqlplus

I run stored Oracle procedure in my batch file and it executed. Now i want to execute the second procedure, but script executes only first. Where i made mistake?

```
#!/bin/bash

sqlplus -s my_scheme@database/pass<<end
execute first_procedure();
commit;
exit;
END


execute second_procedure(); 
commit;
exit;
END
```

I read some internet =) but find information only about running one procedure. Help needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to this:

```
#!/bin/bash

sqlplus -s my_scheme@database/pass<<END
execute first_procedure();
commit;

execute second_procedure(); 
commit;
exit;
END
```

Comment: Yep! It works. I should be more careful with syntax. Thank you one again.

Comment: Phil, thank you. May i be sure that second procedure would not start before first procedure finished?